# Combining multiple 'elsif' statements

Tags: ruby

I try to programm snakes in Ruby. In order to get myself more familiar with Ruby. I define the position of every part of the snake through saving its X and Y value in two 1D arrays one for a X value and one for a Y value.

```
 $x = [2,...]
 $y = [2,...]
```

(What I forgot to tell is that the head of the Snake moves through user input while the rest just inherits its position from the part before like this.)

```
def length(f)
if $length >= f
    $y[f] = $y[f-1]
    $x[f] = $x[f-1]
end
end
```

In order to get a field for the Snake to move around I programmed this.

```
for a in (1..20)  
  for b in (1..20)
    print " X "
  end  
  puts" "  
end
```

Which gives me a 20*20 field.

I then tried to display every part of the snake like on the field like this.(While also drawing a boarder around the field.)

```
for a in (1..20)
for b in (1..20)
    if a == 1 || a == 20
        if b == 1 || b == 20
            print " + "
        else
            print " - "
        end
    elsif b == 1 || b == 20
        print " | "
    elsif a == $x[0] && b == $y[0]
        body
    elsif a == $x[1] && b == $y[1]
        body
    elsif a == $x[2] && b == $y[2]
        body
    elsif a == $x[3] && b == $y[3]
        body
    elsif a == $x[4] && b == $y[4]
        body
    else
        print "   "  
    end

end
puts""
end
```

This works but if the user is really good/ has a lot of spare time I need to make allot of `elsif` for every one represents a part of the snake if the snake should have as a limit a length of 100 I would need to make 100 `elsif` statements.(The body is just:

```
def body
print " # ".green
end
```

)
I tried fixing it with a `for loop` like this:

```
for c in (1..100)
  if a == $x[c] && b == $y[c]
    body
  end
end
```

and this

```
 loop do  
    $x.size.times do |index|
        if $x[index] == a && $y[index] == b
            body
        end
    end
    break
 end
```

But sadly this didn't gave the desired outcome for this interfered with the `if`that draws the boarders of the field.

Is there a way to combine these multiple `elsif` statements?

Every help would be highly appreciated. ( Sorry for being to vague in the first draft.)

Comment: In Ruby it's important to avoid using global variables like `$x` whenever possible. The `$` prefix is not like Perl or PHP where that means simply "variable".

Comment: @tadman I use the `$x` because I need to refer to it in a function. (I added that part to make it easier to understand.)

Comment: That's why functions take arguments, or if that's still inconvenient, objects have instance variables like `@x` that are at least contained in scope.

Comment: Didn't new about instance variables will that work with defining functions?

Comment: They're for instance methods within the context of a class. They persist as long as that object instance does. It's good for preserving data from one method call to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Recommended Refactorings

*NB: You included no sample data in your original post, so your mileage with answers will vary.*

You have a number of issues, not just one. Besides not being DRY, your code is also not very *testable* because it's not broken out into discrete operations. There are a number of things you can (and probably should) do:

1. Break your "body" stuff into discrete methods.
2. Use Array or Enumerator methods to simplify the data.
3. Use dynamic methods to loop over your arrays, rather than fixed ranges or for-loops.
4. Use *case/when* statements inside your loop to handle multiple conditionals for the same variable.

In short, you need to refactor your code to be more modular, and to leverage the language to iterate over your data objects rather than using one conditional per element as you're currently doing.

### Simplify Your Data Set and Handle Procedurally

As an example, consider the following:

```
def handle_matched_values array
end

def handle_mismatched_values array
end

paired_array = a.zip b

matched_pairs   = paired_array.select { |subarray| subarray[0] == subarray[1] }
unmatched_pairs = paired_array.reject { |subarray| subarray[0] == subarray[1] }

matched_pairs.each { |pair| handle_matched_values pair }
matched_pairs.each { |pair| handle_mismatched_values pair }
```

In this example, you may not even need an if statement. Instead, you could use [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-select) or [Array#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-reject) to find indices that match whatever criteria you want, and then call the relevant handler for the results. This has the advantage of being very procedural, and makes it quite clear what data set and handler are being paired. It's also quite readable, which is extremely important.

### Dynamic Looping and Case Statements

If you truly need to handle your data within a single loop, use a case statement to clean up your conditions. For example:

```
# Extract methods to handle each case.
def do_something_with data; end
def do_something_else_with data; end
def handle_borders data; end

# Construct your data any way you want.
paired_array  = a.zip b

# Loop over your data to evaluate each pair of values.
paired_array.each do |pair|
  case pair
  when a == b
    do_something_with pair
  when a == paired_array.first || paired_array.last
     handle_borders pair
  else
     do_something_else_with pair
  end
end
```

There are certainly plenty of other ways to work pairwise with a large data set. The goal is to give you a basic structure for refactoring your code. The rest is up to you!

Comment: I tried to fix my post to make it more specific and easier to understand. In the first version I forgot to tell that I just code for fun and that I use that code  in a game of Snakes.  Still thanks a lot for your answer I gone try to improve on the problems you pointed out, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
(1..20).each do |a|
  (1..20).each do |b|
    if [1, 20].include?(a)
      print([1, 20].include?(b) ? ' + ' : ' - ')

    elsif (1..100).any? { |i| a == $x[i] && b == $y[i] }
      body

    else
      print('   ')
    end

    puts('')
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a good step forward, but isolating the boxing code to wrap around an arbitrary list of strings might clear it up even more.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this would work as a solution even if it is not that advanced?

```
 loop do  
    $x.size.times do |index|
        if $x[index] == a && $y[index] == b
            body
        end
    end
    break
 end
```